# How would I best mark this up in HTML5?

Tags: markup, html

I went to this site: http://www.ignitionmedia.com.au/  and on the front page below the banner is 'WEB DESIGN' , 'WEB DEVELOPMENT' & 'WEBSITE PROMOTION'

I was wondering what would be the best semantic way to mark something like this up in HTML5. Any tips? Eg, should a header tag be present?

My guess might be something along the lines of, are there any better ways?

```
<section id="web-design">

    <h1>WEBSITE DESIGN</h1>

    <img src="img.png" alt="graphic" />

    <p>text here blah blah</p>

</section>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems pretty reasonable, and would work fine once the links have been added and styled.  I think you could probably justify using `article` instead of `section`, since the content in the block stands on its own pretty well, but either one should work.

Here's a flowchart that I've found works well for picking which element is appropriate: http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/uploads/HTML5Doctor-sectioning-flowchart.png

Comment: That's a good link, I'll save that! Do you think the brief content would justify an article markup? Referring back to the website I spoke of, we're talking about 3 articles each with .. a heading? What then contains those 3 articles? A div or aside?

Comment: @John - Since it would just need to collect them for styling purposes, a `div` would be appropriate.  Aside would be inappropriate because it's not just related content - it **is** the content of the page.  Another approach would be to wrap all of the information on the page into an `article`, and then make each one of the blocks a `section`.  It really depends on how you want the content to be related.

Comment: @John - Also, if my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer?